# Magento 2 - site looks destroyed after installing a new module

Tags: magento2, module, magento2.3, extensions, installation

I installed a very simple hello world module which works.

```
php bin/magento module:enable black_test

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

However, now my site looks destroyed. The module is working fine, it is just a controller, so the module did not destroyed my site.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: did you deploy the static content?

Comment: @ASQ, I only did what you can see in my post.

Comment: Check if there is any wrong css or less fine in module, otherwise run command:
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to deploy the static after you run this command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

by running this command

for Magento version 2.2 and above

```
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

OR

php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento s:s:d -f
```

for Magento version 2.1 and below

```
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

 OR

php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento s:s:d
```

After that flush your cache

```
php bin/magento c:f
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the below deployment commands as well after `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

```
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f
```

Also, please check if your pub directory has `.htaccess` file as well.

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: What is this doing? Looks cryptic. Is c:f short for -> cache:flush?

Comment: You need to re-generate the files after running the setup:upgrade command with the above-mentiond commands.